# Can I access recent formula in qgis field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm working with QGIS field calculator and I sometimes need to adjust the formula for a field a little bit. My problem is, that whenever I adjust the formula, I need to type the formula as a whole again. When using the field calculator in ArcGIS the formula is not lost after executing it, is there a way that's possible in QGIS? It costs me so much unnecessary time and effort...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a `recent` tab in field calculator with access to all recent formula used. See image below.

[image: Calculator recent]

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can go to Processing > History...

Here you have all the history functions.